# Setting Instance Type in Sagemaker Experiements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Im pretty new to sagemaker had a quick question

Using experiments in Sagemaker Studio it spins up ml.m5.4xlarge instance automatically

Is there anyway of setting a smaller instance size.... maybe to one that fits under the free tier....

Just playing around with experiments and will require a few runs so want to keep the cost down to start with?

TIA

Comment: could you please post the code you use ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a SageMaker Experiments, there is an associated TrainingJob or Processing Job with that Experiment. It is the Training/Processing Job that spins up the instanc. That is where you can edit the instance type. Experiments itself is available to no extra cost when using SageMaker Studio.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own.